# Excel VBA function that returns all data to a new sheet

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, excel-2010, vba

How can I create a function that will apply predefined filters etc, and then generate a new sheet with that data?

I just need the create new sheet part.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a predefined template sheet and make a copy:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = '... (set the workbook here where you want your new sheet to be copied)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NameOfYourTemplate").Copy _
  after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
```